# How do I use a recursive algorithm to determine whether the array contains two elements that sum to a given integer?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, set

Okay guys thanks for all the help! Special thanks to @pjs for giving me an idea of how to do it. Here is my new code, but for some reason it won't reach one of the base cases. Sorry if I deleted the old code, this is the first time I posted here and I am not sure if I should answer my own question with the new code.

```
//initialized int start = 0
//initialized int end = length of the array
//here goes the constructor

public boolean kPairSum(Integer k) {
        if (sortedIntegerArray.length < 2) {      //if array is less than two return false
            return false;
        }
        else if (start == end) {                  //once the start and the end meets. This is the base case that doesn't seem to work for me.
            return false;
        }
        else {
            int currentStart = sortedIntegerArray[start];   //get first int in the array
            int currentEnd = sortedIntegerArray[end-1];     //get the very last int in the array
            int sum = currentStart + currentEnd;            //get the sum 

            if (k.equals(sum)) {                            //compare sum and k if equal
                return true;
            }
            else if (sum <k) {                              //if sum is less than k then increment value of start
                start++; 
                return kPairSum(k);
            }
            else if (sum > k) {                             //if sum is greater than k then it decrements value of end
                end--;
                return kPairSum(k);
            }
            else {                                          //not sure if this is right, should I just get rid of the else if statement for sum > k and change it to just an else? I wrote this down cause it has to return a type of boolean.
                return kPairSum(k);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your approach of "checking every single possible pair in the array" is not O(n) - there are O(n^2) such pairs. O(n) (average case) solution requires O(n) extra space, using a hash table

Comment: At first glance it's never going to call your recursive function return kPairSum(k) because of the if/else statements.

Comment: @jrowe08 Yea I've had a different code that had the recursion call inside the else statement, but it keeps giving me a stackoverflow error, I think it's because my base case was unreachable so I gave up and ended up writing the code like this :(

Comment: @user3303632 it will never call kPairSum and will never increment your x variable as the code stands now

Comment: Never mind I got it, when I set end as length I subtracted 1 to it right away too. So then I just put the variable end for the currentEnd instead of end-1. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is called `sortedIntegerArray`, but you don't seem to be leveraging that fact.

Start by summing the two ends of the array.  If the sum is smaller than `k`, one of the two elements of the sum has to be larger. You can only get a larger value by incrementing the lower index because the elements are ordered.  Similarly, if the sum is larger than `k`, one of the two elements has to be smaller, so you need to decrement the upper index.  In either case, the structure of the problem is the same but you're now operating on a subset of the array specified by which of the indices you incremented/decremented.  Base cases are that you found two values which sum to `k`, or that the indices have met somewhere.  The recursion should leap out at you.  Since each recursive call either increments or decrements a boundary index until they meet in the middle, it's O(n).

Comment: I just realized it now that you've mentioned it. Thanks for the idea! I'll try to see if I could make it work.

Comment: Thanks @pjs really helped me understand on how to code it right recursively

Comment: I'm glad to hear that helped. Recursion is a discovery process, and you learn it best when you see it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive call is never invokes:

```
    if (sum == k) {                     //compare to given k
        return true;
    } else if (xx == sortedIntegerArray.length-1 ||  sum != k) {
        return false;
    }
```

Note that you basically have two choices: `sum==k`, and then - return true, or `sum!=k` - and then return false. The recursive invokation is not reachable.

An `O(n)` (average case) solution can be achieved using a hash table. The idea is to add each element to the hash table while iterating, and check if there is an existing element that completes to `k`.

```
for each element e in arr:
   if e is in table:
       return true
   table.add(k-e)
return false //no pair was found that sums to k
```

A recursive solution that checks all pairs, is basically brute force that is similar to a nested for loop.

```
//i is the index we are now checking, b is a boolean indicating we have already reduced one element
    kSum(k,i,b):
      if i == arr.length
         return false
      if b == true && k == 0:
         return true
      if b == false:
         return kSum(k-arr[i],i+1,true) || kSum(k,i+1,false)
      else:
         return kSum(k,i+1,b)
```

Comment: and a variation of it, if you need to return the array elements that make up the sum instead of the boolean?

Comment: @user1988876 In this case you use a `Map<Integer,Integer>` (instead of a set semantics for the hash table) - where the value is the index that caused the new insertion. Once you find the solution should be true, you have the two indices (one at hand when iterating, the other from the map) and the solution is simple.

Comment: +1yep, makes sense; your logic for using table is explained well above, but the recursive one lacks explanation; especially for the last two return statements..

Comment: @user1988876 That's basically the brute force staff for recursive call. If you haven't chosen a number already - you can either "choose" this number, or not chose it, and if you have already chosen a number - you must go on (until you hit a stop clause).

Comment: you miss the fact, that deducted list is sorted too and it's easy to find a match with O(n). I don't know how to write code in a comment, so I posted one more answer.

Comment: I get the idea here but I have to implement it with only the parameter k in the method.

Answer (score 0):

I have two implementations here: 
One I initially got to work and with Amit answer, I improved it further. It also `prints/return` the `indices` that make up the `sum`. works with both sorted and unsorted array in O(n). ofcourse, this is not `recursive`.

```
    public static void sumArray2(int[] arr, int sum){
        Map <Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0; i < arr.length;i++){
            map.put(arr[i], i);
        }
        for (int i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
            int diff = sum-arr[i];
            if (map.containsKey(diff) && i!=map.get(diff)) {
                System.out.printf("The two indices are %s and %s%n ",i,map.get(diff));
                return ;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("The sum:%s cannot be formed with given array:%s",sum,Arrays.toString(arr));
        return ;
    }

    //returns a boolean if sum could be formed.
        public static boolean sumArray3(int[] arr, int sum){
            Map <Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
                int diff = sum-arr[i];
                if (map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                    System.out.printf("The two indices are %s and %s%n ",i,map.get(arr[i]));
                    return true;
                }
                map.put(diff,i);
            }
            System.out.printf("The sum:%s cannot be formed with given array:%s",sum,Arrays.toString(arr));
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I've tried it this way but sadly I have to implement it using recursion :(

Answer (score 0):

don't know how to add formatted comment, so here is enhanced version, than Amit provided, works with O(n) :)

```
def check(source, need):
  target = [need-i for i in source]
  target.reverse()
  i = 0
  j = 0
  # walk thru lists same "merge" to find a match
  for i in xrange(0, len(source)):
    while j < len(target) and source[i] > target[j]:
      j=j+1
    if i != len(source)-j-1 and j < len(target) and source[i] == target[j]:
      return True
  return False
```